# Calling functions from Process blocks

Tags: powershell

I would like to call a particular function from within both the Process and End blocks in my PowerShell script. Here is the minimal code:

```
# MyScript.ps1

function MyFunc
{
    "hello"
}

Begin 
{
}

Process 
{
    MyFunc
}

End 
{
    MyFunc
}
```

This code however does not execute. I get this error:

> Begin : The term 'Begin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **`begin` / `process` / `end` (and `dynamic`) blocks** can only ever be used **as the *only* top-level constructs**:

- in a *script file* (`*.ps1`)
- in a *function*

In both cases, no other top-level code is allowed (apart from a `param(...)` parameter-declaration block at the top), a constraint that the placement of your script-internal `MyFunc` function violates.

If you want your script **to use an internal helper function, place it inside the `begin` block** - you'll be able to call it from the `process` / `end` blocks as needed:

```
Begin {
  function MyFunc {
    "hello"
  }
}

Process {
  MyFunc
}

End {
  MyFunc
}
```

The above yields:

```
hello
hello
```

That is, both the `process` and the `end` block successfully called the `MyFunc` function nested inside the `begin` block.

Generally, note that **the `begin` / `process` / `end` blocks share the same local scope**, which also applies to *variables*, so, similarly, you can initialize a script/function-local variable in the `begin` block and access it in the `process` block, for instance.
By the same token, nested functions - such as `MyFunc` here - are local to the enclosing script/function.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use begin/process/end in a script, you cannot have any other functions at the top level. Instead, you will define your internal functions within the `begin` block, and the remaining blocks will also have access to it.

```
begin 
{
    function MyFunc
    {
        Write-Host "Hello"
    }

    MyFunc
}

process {
    MyFunc
}

end {
    MyFunc
}
```